# URL decode and redirect using httpd.conf(apache)

Tags: redirect, apache-2.2, configuration

I'm using apache2.2

```
http://my.site.com/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
->
Redirect 301 http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need php and do redirection.

```
<?php
header("Location: {$_GET['redirection']}";
?>
```

you can also use

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.askdavetaylor.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

as described on dave website: http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_add_a_301_redirect_to_my_apache_httpdconf.html

Comment: Thank you for replying. but I have to resolve by using only apache conf and have to decode url=$1